# Object pass itself to class constructor

Tags: c++, class, game-development, raylib

I'm trying to code a simple game, where the `main.cpp` file instantiates the `Game` class, and the `Game` class instantiates the `Player` class. I want the `Player` class to have access to the `Game` class' variables, so I guess the best way to do that is to have the `Game` class pass itself to the `Player` class:

game.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <raylib.h>
#include "player.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void run();

private:
    void update();
    void draw();

    Player player;
};
```

game.cpp

```cpp
#include "game.h"

Game::Game() : player(this, { 0, 0, 0 })
{
    
}

void Game::run()
{
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "teste");

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        update();
        draw();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}

void Game::update()
{
    player.update();
}

void Game::draw()
{
    BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
    EndDrawing();
}
```

player.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <raylib.h>
#include "game.h"

class Player
{
public:
    Player(Game* game, Vector3 pos);

    void update();
    void draw();

    Game* game;

    Vector3 pos;
};
```

player.cpp

```cpp
#include "player.h"

Player::Player(Game* game, Vector3 pos)
{
    this->game = game;
    this->pos = pos;
    speed = .1;
}

void Player::update()
{
    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_D)) pos.x += 1;
    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_A)) pos.x += -1;
    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_S)) pos.z += 1;
    if (IsKeyDown(KEY_W)) pos.z += -1;
}

void Player::draw()
{
    
}
```

The code seems fine to Intellisense, but the compiler just throws a bunch of errors.

I tried passing `this` as an argument to the `Player` class constructor, but it didn't work out, as the compiler doesn't accept it.

Comment: And what are those compiler errors?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **circular dependency** between your header files.

`game.h` depends on `player.h`, because the `Game::player` member is a `Player` instance, not a `Player*` pointer or `Player&` reference, so the complete `Player` class declaration is needed.  This is fine.

However, `player.h` depends on `game.h`, but `Game` hasn't been declared yet (because of the header guard in `game.h`) when the `Player` class declaration is compiled.

Since the `Player::game` member is just a `Game*` pointer, you can use a **forward declaration** to break that header dependency, eg:

game.h

```
#pragma once

//#include <raylib.h> // <-- game.h doesn't use anything from this, so move it to game.cpp
#include "player.h" // <-- needed here because of Game::player

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void run();

private:
    void update();
    void draw();

    Player player;
};
```

game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"
#include <raylib.h> // <-- move here

Game::Game() : player(this, { 0, 0, 0 })
{
    
}

...
```

player.h

```
#pragma once

#include <raylib.h> // <-- leave here if it declares Vector3
//#include "game.h" // <-- move to player.cpp

class Game; // <-- use this forward declaration instead

class Player
{
public:
    Player(Game* game, Vector3 pos);

    void update();
    void draw();

    Game* game;

    Vector3 pos;
};
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "game.h" // <-- move here

Player::Player(Game* game, Vector3 pos)
{
    this->game = game;
    ...
}

...
```

In short, a header file should `#include` only the things it actually uses *directly*.  Anything else should be `#include`'d in the `.cpp` file instead.  But, anything in a header file that is just a pointer or reference can be forward-declared without using an `#include`.  Keep your `#include`s to a minimum in header files.  The compilation process will be cleaner and more efficient because of it.

Comment: @RodrigoMüller side note: Be careful not to let `Player`'s constructor use the `Game` it got. The `Game` hasn't finished construction yet and things could get ugly. Storing a pointer to it is fine.